# What does a $3D$ Penrose diagram look like?

Tags: visualization

A quick google search turns up many images of $2D$ Penrose diagrams but no $3D$ ones.

> Q: What does a $3D$ Penrose diagram look like?

Comment: In a Carter-Penrose diagram spacetime is asumed to be spherically symmetrical, so up to symmetry only one space coordinate is needed. Adding a second space axis would then not capture or reveal any new information. If you want to add something other than a space axis, then how it would look like depends on what is it that you are adjoining.

Comment: Can I add an entropy axis?

Comment: @RandyMarsh are penrose diagrams causal diamonds?